# Neo4j performance in A <- B -> C structure

Tags: performance, neo4j

All the examples given by neo4j documentation structure the nodes like this:

```
A -> B -> C    (me -> friend -> friend_of_friend)
```

However, my structure is something like:

```
A <- B -> C (product <- sales -> customer)
```

Where the sales nodes are the most important. But when I try to find this path, neo4j takes ages and then blocks.

Am I allowed to have a structure like this? Can I do something to improve the timings?

@EDIT

Create sale nodes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Sales" AS r FIELDTERMINATOR '   '
CREATE (:Sales {order: r.Order, orderLine: r.OrderLine, quantity: r.Quantity});
CREATE INDEX ON :Sales(order);
CREATE INDEX ON :Sales(orderLine);
```

Create product nodes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Product" AS r FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
CREATE (:Product {productKey: r.ProductKey, color: r.Color});
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(productKey);
```

Create customer nodes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Customer" AS r FIELDTERMINATOR '    '
CREATE (:Customer {customerKey: r.CustomerKey, firstName: r.FirstName});
CREATE INDEX ON :Customer(customerKey);
```

Relationships:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Sales" AS r FIELDTERMINATOR '   '
MATCH (sales:Sales {order: r.Order, orderLine: r.OrderLine})
MATCH (customer:Customer{customerKey: r.CustomerKey})
MERGE (sales)-[:CUSTOMER]->(customer);


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Sales" AS r FIELDTERMINATOR '   '
MATCH (sales:Sales {order: r.Order, orderLine: r.OrderLine})
MATCH (product:Product {productKey: r.ProductKey})
MERGE (sales)-[:PRODUCT]->(product);
```

I was trying to do this:

```
MATCH (p:Product) <- (s:Sales) -> (c:Customer)
WHERE p.color = 'blue'
RETURN p.productKey, p.color, s.order, c.customerKey
```

ps: To tell the truth, my structure is even more complex. Besides the customer and the product nodes I also have "date" nodes and "promotion" nodes, all of them connected to the sale nodes.

Comment: Can you paste in the exact Cypher you're using, and also let us know the indexes and constraints you've created?

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks for the reply. I edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding details.

A couple other recommendations... the PROFILE keyword is very useful here to see what your query is doing so you can tune it. And if the query doesn't finish, use EXPLAIN instead of PROFILE.

My first question is if you want to do any kind of aggregation in your query. As it stands now, each line will have a unique combination of :Product, :Sales, and :Customer, so if multiple :Customers are customers of a :Sale, you'll have multiple rows for the same :Product and :Sale. Likewise with :Products, if :Products can be involved in multiple sales. If you need to do some kind of aggregation, like getting a list of customers involved with the sale of a product, then that may reduce the rows you output.

As far as performance tips, I'd try to first match on the node that you are going to apply the constraint on, then with that match on the rest of the pattern. Also, use relationship type in your pattern matching.

```
PROFILE MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE p.color = 'blue'
WITH p
MATCH (p)<-[:PRODUCT]-(s:Sales)-[:CUSTOMER]-> (c:Customer)
RETURN p.productKey, p.color, s.order, c.customerKey
```

Give that a try, and if it's still too slow, add your PROFILE output to your description (after expanding all nodes).

It may also help to figure out the size of the returned data set, so you may want to do `RETURN COUNT(*)` as the last line.